# how to stop or wait other api call untill token is stored in angular12

Tags: typescript, angular12

Hi im calling a token api from my app.component. Reason why im calling it from app.component is that, i dont have any login page. After getting the access token, im storing it in local storage.
Issue is that the token is not getting attached to the http headers for other apis. They are asynchronously called from other components. So they doesnt wait for my token api to execute.

But when im trying to call it again , it is working fine as expected. My requirement is that other request should be called after the execution of token api,

I have tried so many things like delay(),timer() but doesn't work. Please help me

**Httpinterceptor**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
request = request.clone({
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Token': localStorage.getItem('accessToken') || '',
    })

  })
     return next.handle(request)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tap()**. I'm using this in my Authgard in canActivate(). It will wait until your service has loaded and stored the datas locally.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.yourService.yourFunction().pipe(
            tap(yourBoolean => {
                if (!yourBoolean ) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/otherpage']);
                }
            }),
        );
}
```

-> https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap